# what is error id 220 while validating topology in ArcGis10.2?

Tags: topology, validating

**I am getting "validate topology failed" while validating in ArcGis 10.2(Trial Version)**

[image]
[image]

**Please tell me what this error is and how to rectify it ?**

Answer (score 0):

Just got that error now. Seems like error 220 is related to having too much error on a single feature. I solved this by chopping up my data into several parts, and individually topo-validated each part. Finally, I merged the parts back together to get the original data extent.